# Mixing Devexpress WPF and Winform controls: Datasource

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, wcf, devexpress

I'm trying to use the Devexpress Winform scheduler (a Gantt chart ultimately) in an otherwise WPF application. I manage to host the Winform controller in a WPF window and so far so good.

The issue arises when trying to add a Datasource to the Scheduler -- The datasource in this case being a service reference to WCF -- For one, when trying to discover existing services (*Even though one already exists*), nothing is found, and when trying to add one, while it is added correctly, the list of datasources for the chart still is empty.

I've added a screen to illustrate:
[image]

*You can see that the list of datasources is locked on "none", even though by this time I have 5 service references*

Is there some conflict over WCF when hosting a Winform control in a WPF app? Or is this issue inherent to Devexpress as a whole? And most importantly, how can I fix this?

Comment: You might want to post this question on the DevExpress forums as well - in my experience, they're very quick to answer (around 1 day).   They do answer questions here as well.

Comment: @Tim I did. They have never tested this controller in those particular conditions apparently. I'll try updating my question first thing in the morning.